# Compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}$

Tags: calculus

This is what I've done so far:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^2}{n!} = 1 +4 +4.5 + \frac 83 + \frac{25}{24} +\frac{3}{10} + \frac {49}{720} +\dots$$

I know I need to manipulate $\frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}=\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}=$

Comment: Your first step should probably be to make sure it actually converges (it does, but you need to prove it anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Using the standard Maclaurin series for $e^x$, we find that
$$xe^x=\sum_0^\infty 
\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}.$$
Differentiating we get
$$xe^x+e^x=\sum_0^\infty (n+1)\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Multiply by $x$, and differentiate again. We get
$$x^2e^x+3xe^x+e^x=\sum_0^\infty (n+1)^2\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Finally, set $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1=n(n-1)+3n+1$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\displaystyle x\cdot e^x=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}$$
differentiate and again multiply $x$ then put $x=1$